# Можно ли в TypeConverter забиндить внешнее событие для объекта?

Tags: c#, winforms, vb.net, propertygrid

К примеру есть такой конвертер.
Можно ли привязать внешнее событие к объекту который доступен по `context` или как то другим способом?

```vb
Imports System
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Globalization


''' <summary>
''' TypeConverter для редактируемых коллекций
''' </summary>
Friend Class CollectionTypeConverter
    Inherits TypeConverter
    ' Methods
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Только в строку
    ''' </summary>
    Public Overrides Function CanConvertTo(ByVal context As ITypeDescriptorContext, ByVal destType As Type) As Boolean
        Return (destType Is GetType(String))
    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' И только так
    ''' </summary>
    Public Overrides Function ConvertTo(ByVal context As ITypeDescriptorContext, ByVal culture As CultureInfo, ByVal value As Object, ByVal destType As Type) As Object
        Return "< Список... >"
    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: Можете добавить чуть больше деталей или пример, как Вы бы хотели, чтобы это работало? Просто сейчас не совсем ясно, чего Вы пытаетесь достичь

Comment: Если я Вас правильно понял, и в конвертере Вы хотите описать какие-то побочные эффекты в духе создания обработчиков событий, то я бы крайне не советовал это делать, так как код должен быть прозрачным и понятным. Если сторонний человек возьмёт и пропустит через Ваш конвертер *нечто*, ожидая при этом получить другое независимое *нечто*, а впридачу получит непонятно откуда взявшееся событие, он точно не будет Вам благодарен ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Суть TypeConveterter'a заключается в том, чтобы спроецировать объекты множества А в объекты множества Б, здесь попросту не должно быть никаких сторонних эффектов

Comment: Эффекты мне нужны в моей программе и ни кому более, я не разрабатывают конвертер для других.

Comment: @Kir_Antipov Хотел бы вызвать внешнее событие из конвертера в объекте который я редактирую, по моему очевидно.

Comment: Я понимаю, но есть старая добрая поговорка: "Всегда пишите код так, будто поддерживать его придётся неуравновешенному психопату, который знает, где вы живете". Даже в домашнем проекте придерживайтесь лучших практик, ищите решения не для того, чтобы просто побыстрее решить задачу, а ищите наиболее правильные решения. Пока же Вы собираетесь забивать гвозди микроскопом :) Собственно, никто не может Вам этого запретить, но посоветовать все таки использовать для этих целей молоток - стоит :)

Comment: @Kir_Antipov Скажите почему когда первыми словами в вопросе, стоят "Можно ли ..." начинается палемика на неделю, вместо того что бы ответить, да можно так то, или нет точно на 1000% нельзя и привести доводы почему? Вопрос не о том как правильно проектировать то или иное, вопрос как сделать сейчас, ибо завтра нечем платить за кредит и нет времени на палемику...

Comment: Просто все заботятся друг о друге и пытаются не допустить применения коллегами нехороших практик, не принимайте так близко к сердцу

Comment: Собственно, по вопросу: Вам нужно навесить событие на объект, который улетел в конвертер, так?

Comment: @Kir_Antipov А вам не приходило в голову, что вы можете породить того психопата который захочет узнать где вы живете?

Comment: @Kir_Antipov Да собственно хочу навесить событие и дернуть его из конвертера. Если такое возможно.

Comment: Вам когда-нибудь приходилось поддерживать код латышского PHP-программиста, который в добавок к далеко не лучшим практикам давал переменным названия на родном языке? Надеюсь, что нет, ибо этого врагу не пожелаешь 0_• Вот чтобы меньше сталкиваться с таким кодом, а также минимизировать порицание в сторону коллег-программистов, люди вроде меня и начинают отступать от первоначального вопроса, советуя в корень изменить подход к делу. Подчеркну, что я никоим образом не хотел Вас как-то задеть или сказать, что Ваш вопрос даже как теоретический не имеет права на существование

Comment: У `ConvertTo` есть параметр `value`, приведённый к базовому `Object`. Приведите его к необходимому типу и получите доступ желаемому событию) К примеру, если бы `value` было `Button`, то `((Button)value).OnClick += (s, e) => ...;` (извините, что в нотациях `C#`, VB только читать умею))

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101034/discussion-between---and-kir-antipov).